# I am getting a salesforce flow error mail "Probably limit exceeded or 0 Recipients" Can anyone guide me how to resolve or find the root cause of error

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-communities

I have created a flow for the users registering on community page. once they register they receive a mail of registration on community. once they register a record gets created in a particular object. as soon as the record gets created the flow gets triggered and a mail alert is sent to the user.

But I am receiving errors of flow breaking